# css: linking images to urls

Tags: css, image, imageurl

I got confused a little wondering how to link my images to their urls in each page. let me explain a little. I actually have this site structure:

```
                                                    ------> folder1-1 
                                    ------> folder1 ------> folder1-2
                                                    ------> folder1-3

                                                    ------> folder2-1 
www.domain.com ------> main folder  ------> folder2 ------> folder2-2
                                                    ------> folder2-3

                                                    ------> folder3-1 
                                    ------> folder3 ------> folder3-2
                                                    ------> folder3-3
```

when I get to linking images in each page things change; I mean I have to modify the url destination. for example, the main folder can get the images directly from the source so the url will look like this `"../images/bla.jpg"`

however, the further I go, the longer it gets; i.e: **for folder2** : `"../../images/bla.jpg"` and so on for the others...

I have my images folder in the root where main folder is placed so their are parallel to each other.

I found 4 ways to resolve this:

**1-** placing the full url to the link directly; i.e: "http://www.domain.com/images/bla.jpg"  (I don't know yet if that effect the site speed; slowing it down or not)

**2-** going crazy and add `../../../` the further I go in the site (which I think none-sense.

**3-** bringing all folders in line "parallel to each other" so all of them are placed in the root an the image folder can pass directly to each page.

**4-** using external css file to contain all images I need for each page (but I think I will have to use the full url to connect it to each page or the same long `../../../` way)

Now my question is, Can I use images with my original structure without messing things directly to each page and without adding the full url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use a leading slash to denote that the request starts from the root of the domain. So `/images/bla.jpg` will translate to `http://www.domain.com/images/bla.jpg` no matter how deeply you're nested.

As a side note, point number **1**, using `http://www.domain.com/images/bla.jpg`, won't affect speed in any way. No matter how the URL is phrased it'll be broken down by the browser and sent the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a root relative url (leading slash - relative to the root directory), *viz*:

```
/images/foo.jpg
```

That will be consistent no matter where the page (or style sheet) is